# What does the abbreviation "adhib." mean in historiography or archival science?

Tags: historiography, language, sources, terminology, latin-language

What does the abbreviation

*adhib.*

mean in the context of historiography and archival science?

**Remarks.**

- This question is not about the meaning in medicine. This is easy to look  up.
- Of course, literally it seems to mean 'to be administered/used', so my guess is that the abbreviation is used to *emphasize what part of the given reference is relevant to the topic at hand*.
- An example of the use I am asking an explanation of is to be found in the book

> James C. Albisetti, ''Secondary School Reform in Imperial Germany''
>   Princeton University Press, 2014
>   ISBN 1400853087
>   380 pages

where e.g. on page 229 the abbreviation is used in a footnote:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is short for [`adhibendum`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adhibendus#Latin). I think the English equivalent would be something along the lines of "annex" or "appendix". As in, "Appendix B, Vol II, *Proceedings of the School Conference of 1891*".

I don't believe this is a general history convention. As far as I can determine, it's mainly a German usage; the example you gave is also citing a German publication.